# Magento Shipment email and adding survey URL

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to add a custom survey URL at the top and bottom of the email template.

I'm using a very basic/stock template from magento.  I have developed two templates to help with generating the URL:

surveyurl.phtml - contains some logic to generate a URL

```
$surveys = array("somesurvey.com/1", "somesurvey.com/2");
$pick_survey_key = array_rand($surveys);
$url = $surveys[$pick_survey_key];
if($_order){
    $survey_url = $url ."?order=". $_order->getIncrementId();
}
if ($coupon_code){
    $survey_url .= "&code=". $coupon_code;
}
echo $survey_url;
```

survey.phtml - contains the html that shows up in the footer of the email.

```
<?php $_shipment=$this->getShipment() ?>
<?php $_order=$this->getOrder() ?>
<?php $coupon_code = $_order->getCouponCode(); ?>
<?php
  if($_order) {

  //get $survey_url from surveyurl.phtml

}
?>
<?php if ($_shipment && $_order): ?>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Help us by taking a survey!') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_shipment->getAllTracks() as $_item): $i++ ?>
        <tr <?php echo $i%2?'bgcolor="#F6F6F6"':'' ?>>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:3px 9px">
                <a href ="<?php echo $survey_url ?>">Take our survey!</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:3px 9px" colspan="1">
                *You will get something cool at the end ;)
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

in my local.xml i added:

```
<sales_email_order_surveyurl>
        <block type="core/template" name="survey_url" template="email/order/shipment/surveyurl.phtml"> 
        </block>
    </sales_email_order_surveyurl>
```

then in my email template i add this to get it at the top:

```
<p>Survey URL: 
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_surveyurl" order=$order}}</p>
```

and I add this at the bottom:

```
<td>{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/survey.phtml' order=$order}}</td>
```

So my question: how can I pass the url that is generated in surveyurl.phtml into survey.phtml?  Or how do I need to set it up differently to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is your logic to generate the url in a template?

I would put it in a block, and your template should be of that block type.

Then it would be as simple as calling $this->getSurveyUrl()

Your block type could extend  Mage_Sales_Block_Items_Abstract so that you have getOrder() and getShipment() functions available to you.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Took your idea and now I have the URL constructor that I can call at anytime.